# Why is 'No viable operator overload'?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a 2D array class and trying to overload the operator[]:

```
typedef unsigned long long int dim;

template<typename N>
class Array2D {

private:

    dim _n_rows;
    dim _n_cols;
    vector<vector<N>> M;

public:

    dim n_rows() { return _n_rows; }
    dim n_cols() { return _n_cols; }
    Array2D(): _n_rows(0), _n_cols(0), M(0, vector<N>(0)){}
    Array2D (const dim &r, const dim &c) : _n_rows(r), _n_cols(c), M(r, vector<N>(c)) {}

    void set(const dim &i, const dim &j, const N &elem) { M[i][j] = elem; } // Works fine
    vector<N>& operator[](int &index) { return M[index]; } // <- PROBLEM
};
```

The way I see it: operator [] returns something (vector) which in turn has the overloaded operator[]. That's why I think that

```
Array2D<int> L(10, 10);
L[3][3] = 10;
```

should work.

Apparently, the compiler doesn't think so, saying that '*No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'Array2D'* What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

PS. XCode 7, if that matters.

Comment: Why do you take the int as reference?

Comment: this works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/841cd49502f05fe9

Comment: @m.s. Hmm, so is it a compiler-related issue?

Comment: @alekscooper No he removed the `&` in his sample.

Comment: Please include the *complete* error, including any information notes. Also please create create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @alekscooper no, I modified `operator[](int index)` to not take a reference as its parameter

Comment: Oh, I see. I used reference not to make a copy of the parameter, not to pass it by value in other words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function:

```
vector<N>& operator[](int &index)
```

Cannot be called like this:

```
Array2D<int> L(10, 10);
L[3][3] = 10;
```

Because a non-const reference to a literal cannot be taken.  References allow modification, and what would it mean to modify `3`?

You should use this instead:

```
vector<N>& operator[](size_t index)
```